# Twilio Call disconnects after one ring

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

Twilio calls gets automatically disconnect after one ring. When it's the case for cell phone, everything works just fine but for the landline having ring back-tone the call gets disconnected after one ring. I have checked the call logs; and the status for each call was completed but the duration of each call was 3sec.

This is the code that I have wrote:

```php
$sid    = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$token  = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);
            
$call = $twilio->calls
               ->create("+1XXXXXXX", // to
                        "+1XXXXXX", // from
                        [
                           "twiml" => "<Response><Say>Hi, A new order has been made by a customer!</Say></Response>"
                        ]
                       );
```

Comment: Anymore details you can share? Does this happen for all landlines or just a specific landline number? Also, if this is a trial account, is a button being pressed on the dialed end to execute the TwiML.